# Getting "Flush: failed to commit file 1" errors after updating to macOS 13

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, installation

I installed Bitcoin Core v22 on an external drive. It worked. After I updated to macOS 13, the wallet stopped running. I tried to reinstall and also tried v23. But it wouldn't do it. When loading blocks, it gives an error - `ERROR: Flush: failed to commit file 1`. Please help install the wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all very much for the replies. The problem is with the update Ventura. After installing 13 Mac Os, the wallet does not work. I returned back 12 Monterey and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to recent [stability issues](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/26490) caused by the macOS Ventura 13 release for the Bitcoin Core GUI. The [fix](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/gui/pull/680) was backported to the 22 and 23 branches and should be coming out soon.

Answer (score 0):

Updating from Ventura 13.0.1 to 13.2.1 fixed this issue for me.